# Why is Number([]) === 0 and Number({}) === NaN in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the first table on http://zero.milosz.ca/, and wanted to understand why, for example, `0 == []` and `0 != {}`. I'm assuming it's because `Number([]) == 0` and `Number({}) == NaN`. However, that part seems arbitrary. Why is an empty list `0` and empty object a `NaN`?

Comment: Arrays are weird like that. Like `[[[[[[[[123]]]]]]]] == 123`.

Comment: @Kolink ...but what causes this to work? (What rule of `==`, not found in `===`, is being applied?)

Comment: @Kolink: You call *that* weird? [`(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]] === 'fail'`](http://wtfjs.com/2010/07/12/fail)

Comment: @pst: The strict comparison returns false if the operands are not of the same type (as you probably know). But `==` will convert both operands to numbers in this case.

Comment: The general answer to this class of question is: "Because that's how Javascript's insane type coercion rules work out."

Comment: @FelixKling True, well "skipping that" ;-)

Comment: Why does the title refer to `===` but the body use `==`? Which one(s) is the question actually asking about?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `Number(some_object)` will use the string representation of the given object. For your examples the string representations are:

```
js> ({}).toString();
[object Object]
js> [].toString();

js>
```

The string `'[object Object]'` cannot be converted to a number but the empty string `''` can.

Comment: But why is the empty string `''` converted to 0?

Comment: It is pretty common that falsy values are converted to 0 when used in a numeric context. Empty objects are *not* falsy by the way.

Comment: @tskuzzy: Because it is defined this way: *"The MV of StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty] is 0."*. See http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1

Answer (score 9):

To elaborate a bit on ThiefMaster's answer, I've taken a look into ECMAScript's [specifications](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1):

When converting a string into a number, a grammar is used for the conversion. In particular, the mathematical value of `StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty]` is defined as 0. In fact, it's 0 for any whitespace.

Comment: For those who are too lazy to search for this in the PDF, http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1 is the relevant section of the spec.

Answer (score 2):

When one value is an object ([],{}) and the other is a number or string, operator == converts the object to a primitive value (a number in this case) using the built-in conversion methods which all objects in Javascript inherit: *toString()* and *valueOf()*.

For generic objects like {}, *valueOf* is used, and by default it returns the object itself, which is != 0.

For built-in arrays, *toString* is used. This method applied to an array returns a string containing all the elements joined by commas. For the empty array, it returns an empty string, ''.

Then the interpreter applies *valueOf* to that string; the return value of this method for an empty string is 0, so [] == 0.